# How do I use django @lazy decorator?

Tags: python, django, lazy-evaluation, python-decorators

First try with the django.utils.functional.lazy decorator. My function returns two lists, so I'm decorating it with @lazy(list, list). It's a plain jane function, not a method/property on a class.

I'm getting a "'**proxy**' object is not callable" when I try to call the resulting decorated function.

Comment: that one is great for methods/properties on a class but doesn't work on plain functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can use Django's lazy as decorator. You can use it as a function call:

```
lazy_function = lazy(f, type)
```

where `f` is the function you need to make lazy and `type` is the expected data type.

Also how do you return the two lists? Like:

```
def a():
    return [], []
```

If yes, then technically you are returning a tuple hence you should use lazy as:

```
lazy_f = lazy(f, tuple)
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right- I wrongly assumed it'd been written as a decorator.

Comment: If you really need a decorator, I am working on a django library which provides one. You can take a look at https://github.com/miki725/django-auxilium/blob/develop/django_auxilium/utils/functools/lazy.py. Any feedback would be appreciated. You can of course file issues if you find anything wrong.